# Uniform best approximation in Chebyshev/Haar systems and the necessity of compactness of the function domain.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, compactness

A great deal of Chebyshev/Haar systems are given for intervals $]-\infty,\infty[$, $[0,\infty[$ and other noncompact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Nonetheless, the theory of uniform best approximations in Chebyshev/Haar spaces and in specific Haar's theorem assumes that the functions of interest are defined on a compact subspace $A$ of Euclidean space $E^n$ or in general a compact Hausdorff space $X$. What is the main reason for the requirement that $A$ is compact?

Comment: Uniform approximation on unbounded sets is rarely possible. E.g., one cannot uniformly approximate $\sin x$ by polynomials on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Chebyshev/Haar spaces are finite-dimensional subspaces $W$ of a normed vector space $V$ so a best approximation to a point $x \in V$ within this subspace should always exist. My question still remains where the necessity of compactness comes in to play.